# Parsing with placeholders

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the different variations of this webpage.For instance the code that should scrape this webpage http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=11849.
should be the same as the code i use to scrape this webpage
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&sub=view&ID=11849

```
def extract_contact(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    tbl=soup.findAll('table')[2]
    list=[]
    Contact=tbl.findAll('p')[0]

    for br in Contact.findAll('br'):
        next = br.nextSibling
        if not (next and isinstance(next,NavigableString)):
            continue
        next2 = next.nextSibling
        if next2 and isinstance(next2,Tag) and next2.name == 'br':  
            text = re.sub(r'[\n\r\t\xa0]','',next).replace('Phone:','').strip()
            list.append(text)
    print list      

    #Street=list.pop(0)
    #CityStateZip=list.pop(0)
    #Phone=list.pop(0)
    #City,StateZip= CityStateZip.split(',')
    #State,Zip= StateZip.split(' ') 
    #ContactName = Contact.findAll('b')[1]
    #ContactEmail = Contact.findAll('a')[1]
    #Body=tbl.findAll('p')[1]
    #Website = Contact.findAll('a')[2]
    #Email = ContactEmail.text.strip()
    #ContactName = ContactName.text.strip()
    #Website = Website.text.strip()
    #Body = Body.text
    #Body = re.sub(r'[\n\r\t\xa0]','',Body).strip()
    #list.extend([Street,City,State,Zip,ContactName,Phone,Email,Website,Body])
    return list
```

The way i believe i will need to write the code in order it to work, is to set it up so that print list returns the same number of values, ordered identically.Currently, the above script returns these values

[u'2133 Craigs Store Road', u'Afton,VA 22920', u'434-882-3150']
[u'Alexandria,VA 22305']

Accounting for missing values,in order to be able to parse this page consistently,
I need the print list command to return something similar to this

```
[u'2133 Craigs Store Road', u'Afton,VA 22920', u'434-882-3150']
['',u'Alexandria,VA 22305','']
```

this way i will be able to manipulate values by position(as they will be in consistent order). The problem is that i don't know how to accomplish this as I am still very new to parsing. If anybody has any insight as to how to solve the problem i would be highly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

```
def extract_contact(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    tbl=soup.findAll('table')[2]
    list=[]
    Contact=tbl.findAll('p')[0]

    for br in Contact.findAll('br'):
        next = br.nextSibling
        if not (next and isinstance(next,NavigableString)):
            continue
        next2 = next.nextSibling
        if next2 and isinstance(next2,Tag) and next2.name == 'br':  
            text = re.sub(r'[\n\r\t\xa0]','',next).replace('Phone:','').strip()
            list.append(text)
    Street=[s for s in list if ',' not in s and '-' not in s]
    CityStateZip=[s for s in list if ',' in s]  
    Phone = [s for s in list if '-' in s]
    if not Street:
        Street=''
    else:
        Street=Street[0]    
    if not CityStateZip:
        CityStateZip=''
    else:
        City,StateZip= CityStateZip[0].split(',')
        State,Zip= StateZip.split(' ')  
    if not Phone:
        Phone=''
    else:
        Phone=Phone[0]      
    list=[]
```

I figured out an alternative solution using substrings and if statements. Since there are only 3 values max in the list, all with defining characteristics i realized that i could delegate by looking for special characters rather than the position of the record.